# Slicing strings pulled from HTML

Tags: python, python-unicode

I pulled some data from a webpage using

```
y = soup.find('td', attrs={'data'}).string
```

When I tried to use float() I got the error message that it was an invaled literal for float(). So I tried to find out what was wrong by using print(repr(y)).
That gave me the following result.

```
u'\r\n                450,990\r\n            '
```

I realize u' means unicode, but how can I make this into a format so I can float() it ?

Thanks in advance, first post here so have mercy.

Comment: Use `strip()` on the entire string.

Comment: You simply need to `strip` it and take care for that `,`. Is it used to denote a decimal, or as a thousand separator?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make this clear earlier. It is used to denote a decimal.

Comment: @Kamikazie In this case you can use @Nehal's  answer(http://stackoverflow.com/a/39015487/1453822), but change `replace(',','')` to `replace(',','.')`,

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> y = str(u'\r\n                450,990\r\n            ')
>>> map(float, y.strip().split(','))
[450.0, 990.0]

>>> float(y.strip().replace(',',''))
450990.0

>>> float(y.strip().replace(',','.'))
450.99
```

Comment: The `,` may indicate a decimal in some locales, or used as a thousand separator.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is indeed used as a decimal. Edited your last code a bit and it works now. Thanks very much :) Good first experience of the site.